# Excluir elemento de um array de objeto dinâmico

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

Eu preciso excluir uma coluna de um array de objeto dinâmico.

Exemplo:

```
export interface ObjetoTeste {
  primeiraColuna: string;
  segundaColuna: string;
}

let teste: Array<ObjetoTeste> = [
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste1',
    segundaColuna: 'teste1'
  },
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
    segundaColuna: 'teste2'
  }
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
    segundaColuna: 'teste2'
  }
]

//O header definirá qual coluna será excluída com base no valor XXX
var header: ObjetoTeste = {
  primeiraColuna: 'Juninho',
  segundaColuna: 'XXX',
}
 
// Com base no header, não terá mais a segundaColuna
var semSegundaColuna: Array<ObjetoTeste> = [
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste1',
  },
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
  }
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
  }
];
```

O header é o objeto que define quem será excluído com base no valor XXX recebido na coluna.

Outro Exemplo:

```
export interface ObjetoTeste2 {
   primeiraColuna: string;
   segundaColuna: string;
   terceiraColuna: string;
}

let header: ObjetoTeste2 = {
  primeiraColuna: 'XXX',
  segundaColuna: 'Teste',
  terceiraColuna: 'XXX'
}

//Primeiro irá receber os valores inteiros para então ser tratatos
let teste2: Array<ObjetoTeste2> = [
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste1',
    segundaColuna: 'teste1',
    terceiraColuna: 'teste1'
  },
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
    segundaColuna: 'teste2',
    terceiraColuna: 'teste2'
  }
]

//resultado do tratamento do objeto com base nos valores do header
let resultado: Array<ObjetoTeste2> = [
      {
        segundaColuna: 'teste1',
      },
      {
        segundaColuna: 'teste2',
      }
    ];
```

Comment: *"Com base no header, não terá mais a segundaColuna"* e como o header definiu que não deve ter a segunda coluna? não tem nenhum valor que diga pra remover, precisa esclarecer o critério

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não sei qual é o contexto do sua necessidade de remover as colunas pelo valor “XXX”, isso só valeria a pena se esse valor “XXX” fosse algum retorno de uma API, mas vamos separar o seu problema em dois.

1. primeiro recuperar a lista de colunas a remover.
2. remover a coluna da lista de objeto

Vou apresentar duas soluções um com [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) e outro sem, o delete tem um problema que ele acaba mutando o objeto e por muitas vezes isso pode gerar problemas, o ideal seria criar um método para clonar cada objeto da lista, mas não vou incluir nessa solução já que não é pertinente a pergunta.

**Solução sem delete:**

Primeiro vamos recuperar a lista de colunas a remover, assim ficará mais claro para futuras manutenções:

```js
/*
 * Primeiro vamos recuperar a lista de colunas a remover, 
 * assim ficará mais claro para futuras manutenções:
 */

var header = {
  primeiraColuna: 'XXX',
  segundaColuna: 'Teste',
  terceiraColuna: 'XXX'
}

var colunasParaRemover = Object.entries(header).filter(item => item[1] === "XXX").map(n => n[0]);
console.log(colunasParaRemover);


/*
 * Segundo vamos criar uma função para fazer a remoção, 
 * separando a lógica você obtém algo de fácil manutenção e funções 
 * mais genéricas para utilização no sistema, primeiro vamos criar 
 * uma função que  retorna a lista com as colunas selecionadas
 */

var teste2 = [
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste1',
    segundaColuna: 'teste1',
    terceiraColuna: 'teste1'
  },
  {
    primeiraColuna: 'teste2',
    segundaColuna: 'teste2',
    terceiraColuna: 'teste2'
  }
]

var removeColunadaLista = (listaObjetos, colunasRemover) => {
  colunas = Object.keys(listaObjetos[0]).filter(n => ! colunasRemover.includes(n)); // invetemos montamos uma lista somente das Keys que queremos;
    return listaObjetos.map(objeto => Object.fromEntries(colunas.map(k => [k, objeto[k]]))); // retorna a lista sem a coluna desejada
}

console.log(teste2);
console.log(removeColunadaLista(teste2, colunasParaRemover)); // retorna uma lista de objetos formatado
console.log(teste2); // não altera o a lista principal.
```

**Solução Com Delete:**

Cuidado com essa solução pois ele altera o Objeto em si, lembrando que o array guarda a referência do objeto

```js
var o = {opa: "x", neh: "y", vixi: "z"};
var o2 = {opa: "a", neh: "b", vixi: "c"};
var os = [o, o2];
var dc = ["opa", "vixi"];

os.forEach(n => dc.forEach(c => delete n[c]));

console.log(o); // {neh: "y"}
console.log(o2); // {neh: "b"}
console.log(os); // [{neh: "y"},{neh: "b"} ];
```

Comment: O problema de utilizar `delete` é que, além de modificar o objeto (o que pode ser um problema em algumas situações), cria buracos no array, o que pode ser de fato um problema na ampla maioria dos casos. Teste no console: `let arr = [1, 2, 3]; delete arr[1]; arr;`.

Answer (score -5):

Consegui resolver dessa maneira, onde teste é a variável do array e header o objeto de filtro:

```
let teste3 = teste.map((data) => {
    Object.keys(header).forEach((headerData) => {
      if (header[headerData] == "XXX") {
        delete data[headerData];
      }
    });
});
```